# Streaming a zip file in Python3

Tags: python, django, streaming, zip

In my Django project, I have large zip files I need to send to a user for them to download.
These files can be up to 10Gb big at some points.

The files are already in zip format, and I don't want to extract them.

Instead, I would like to send say 100mb of the file at a time, wait for the frontend to receive them, and then ask for the next 100mb until the file has been completely read. I can handle the collection and download on the frontend, but how can I perform this request in Django?

Disclaimer: I'm a frontend developer, and very new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/travcunn/django-zip-stream? It looks like what you may be looking for.

Example Use Case:

```
from django_zip_stream.responses import TransferZipResponse

def download_zip(request):
    # Files are located at /home/travis but Nginx is configured to serve from /data
    files = [
       ("/chicago.jpg", "/data/home/travis/chicago.jpg", 4096),
       ("/portland.jpg", "/data//home/travis/portland.jpg", 4096),
    ]
    return TransferZipResponse(filename='download.zip', files=files)
```